# Paused radio stream restarts from same position

Tags: ios, iphone, parsing, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming

I'm just learning iOS development and I have an app that use MPMoviePlayerController. The stream I am using plays perfectly but if I press the pause button, the stream starts playing again from the same moment as when I pressed pause. When I press pause, I am looking for it stop the stream. When I restart the stream, I would like it to the load the stream again and play 'live' as it did when I first opened the app.

This is the code that I have used so far (I imagine it's far to simplistic but I am just starting out)...

```
@interface FirstViewController()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize toolbar, play, pause, player;


- (void)viewDidLoad

{
[super viewDidLoad];



self.pause = [[UIBarButtonItem      alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPause target:self action:@selector(playPressed:)];
[self.pause setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];


NSString *streamAddress =@"http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r4_aaclca.pls";
NSURL *address =[NSURL URLWithString:streamAddress];

MPMoviePlayerController *stream = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:address];//instance method to create and intialise the stream

stream.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

stream.view.hidden = YES;
//[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
//[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setActive:YES error:nil];
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

self.player = stream;

[self.view addSubview:self.player.view];




}
```

If anyone could help me in anyway that would be fantastic.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
-(IBAction)playPressed:(id)sender{


MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = [self.player playbackState];
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.toolbar items]];
[self.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
              forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.toolbar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]
          forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny];

if (playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped || playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused){
    NSMutableArray *toolbarButtons = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];

    [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.pause];
    [self setToolbarItems:toolbarButtons animated:YES];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    if (![ toolbarButtons containsObject:self.pause]) {
        [toolbarButtons addObject:self.pause];
        [self setToolbarItems:toolbarButtons animated:YES];
         }

//this means that the player is not currently playing and that the toolbar is displaying the play button
    [self.player play];
    //NSMutableArray *toolbarButtons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[toolbar items]];
    //[toolbarButtons replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:pause];
   // [toolbarButtons removeObject:play];
    //[items replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:self.pause];
}
else if (playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying){
    NSMutableArray *toolbarButtons = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];
    [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.play];
    [self setToolbarItems:toolbarButtons animated:YES];

    if (![ toolbarButtons containsObject:self.play]) {
        [toolbarButtons addObject:self.play];
        [self setToolbarItems:toolbarButtons animated:YES];

    }
    [self.player pause];



}
```

Comment: Could we have the playPressed: method?

Comment: Just edited the question with the playPressed: method. Having trouble with that (the 'pause' item from the toolbar does not display but the 'play' item plays and pauses the stream). Sorry to go off point, the original question is far more important I feel. Thank you again

Comment: Don't pause the stream, simply stop and play it again.

Comment: @Brad thanks very much, that's sorted it perfectly. As you can see clearly, I'm at the very early stages of working with Obj C. Thanks again

Comment: A button can be done.you can use just Image(pause) and highlightImage(play) to change the button state,just like if(button.highlighted) [self pause];else [self play];